# Split then strip txt lines then save to dictionary

Tags: python

I have this .txt file that I wanted to split, strip then save the content to a dictionary

```
Jon, ID1, 30.0, ID2, 35.4, ID3, 478.5
Paige, ID1, 15.8, ID3, 723.5, ID4, 250, ID6, 66.2
Jil, ID1, 46.2, ID2, 37.7, ID3, 68.4, ID4, 40, ID5, 22
Jig5, ID1, 90.5, ID2, 69.4, ID6, 35.8
Kit4, ID3, 700.2, ID4, 260, ID5, 96
```

I wanted to achieve an output that is similar to this

```
Jon {ID1: 30.0, ID2: 35.4, ID3: 478.5}
Paige {ID1: 15.8, ID3: 723.5, ID4: 250, ID6: 66.2}
Jil {ID1: 46.2, ID2: 37.7, ID3: 68.4, ID4: 40, ID5: 22}
Jig5 {ID1: 90.5, ID2: 69.4, ID6: 35.8
Kit4 {ID3: 700.2, ID4: 260, ID5: 96}
```

I have tried:

```
output = {}

with open("records.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in f_in: names = line[0].strip()
        usage = usage[1::2].strip()

        if usage == "":
            continue

        ID, SCORE = usage.split(",")
        output[state] = capital

        print(output)
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Hint: use the built-in `csv` module or 3rd party `pandas.read_csv`.  Lots of duplicates on SO.

Comment: Ok you included your code - this is great. Now you need to add more detail, explaining what the issue is with your code. What does it actually do? Also, that code doesn't really make sense, as you have a variable called `usage` that never appears to be initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
with open(r"records.txt") as f:
    data = {}
    for line in f:
        # Remove the trailing newline character
        line = line.rstrip()
        d = {}
        values = line.split(", ")
        name = values[0]
        
        # This returns a generator which yields the ids and numbers
        # The try-except block is used to keep the numbers the same 
        # as their string representation, e.g. "30.0" as 30.0, and 
        # "96" as 96 (instead of 96.0)
        for key, value in zip(values[1::2], values[2::2]):
            try:
                value = int(value)
            except ValueError:
                value = float(value)
                
            d[key] = value
        
        data[name] = d

with open(r"records (transformed).txt", "w") as f:
    for name, d in data.items():
        values = ", ".join(f"{key}: {value}" for key, value in d.items())
        f.write(f"{name} {{{values}}}\n")
```

records.txt:

```
Jon, ID1, 30.0, ID2, 35.4, ID3, 478.5
Paige, ID1, 15.8, ID3, 723.5, ID4, 250, ID6, 66.2
Jil, ID1, 46.2, ID2, 37.7, ID3, 68.4, ID4, 40, ID5, 22
Jig5, ID1, 90.5, ID2, 69.4, ID6, 35.8
Kit4, ID3, 700.2, ID4, 260, ID5, 96
```

records (transformed).txt:

```
Jon {ID1: 30.0, ID2: 35.4, ID3: 478.5}
Paige {ID1: 15.8, ID3: 723.5, ID4: 250, ID6: 66.2}
Jil {ID1: 46.2, ID2: 37.7, ID3: 68.4, ID4: 40, ID5: 22}
Jig5 {ID1: 90.5, ID2: 69.4, ID6: 35.8}
Kit4 {ID3: 700.2, ID4: 260, ID5: 96}
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:testing.py", line 16, in <module>
    value = int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'S03: 578.5}'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:testing.py", line 18, in <module>
    value = float(value)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'S03: 578.5}'

Comment: It gave me this error @GordonAitchJay

Comment: You seem to be using the output file as your input file. My code works if the input file in formatted like so: `Jon, ID1, 30.0, ID2, 35.4, ID3, 478.5`. For some reason your input file has colons and curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment pointed out, your data is essentially a CSV file. Therefore, you can use the built-in `csv` module. Like this:

```
import csv


def pairs(lst):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), 2):
        yield (lst[i], lst[i + 1])


with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        dct = {k.strip(): v.strip() for (k, v) in pairs(row[1:])}
        print(row[0], dct)
```

The first column is used as a header, while the rest is read in pairs by the helper generator function `pairs()` and put into a dictionary comprehension. I also used `.strip()` on the strings to remove the extra whitespace in your data.

Comment: It yielded an IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Sheesh Are you sure your data has the correct number of pairs? Everything works fine for me.

Comment: @Sheesh From my testing, my code will only return an IndexError if there is an unequal number of IDs and numbers.

Comment: Yes. Same with the data provided above.


Jon, ID1, 30.0, ID2, 35.4, ID3, 478.5

Paige, ID1, 15.8, ID3, 723.5, ID4, 250, ID6, 66.2

Jil, ID1, 46.2, ID2, 37.7, ID3, 68.4, ID4, 40, ID5, 22

Jig5, ID1, 90.5, ID2, 69.4, ID6, 35.8

Kit4, ID3, 700.2, ID4, 260, ID5, 96

Comment: @Sheesh I keep running this code and everything is fine. Are you changing the code or data file?

Comment: @Sheesh Why did you choose to unaccept this answer and accept the other one? Does part of my answer not work for you?

Comment: Both worked for me. I cant choose 2 answers

Comment: @Sheesh Yes, but can you leave a comment explanation why the other one is better for you? This will help others in the future understand better.